# Get users liked photos list on Instagram

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I searched this on here, github and instagram api but couldn't find the answer. I need something like this:

(User1: authenticated user - User2: un-authenticated user)

- User1 will login with the Instagram access.
- User1 will enter User2's id and will see the photos User2 liked or commented.

On instagram api, it just gives photos that authenticated user liked. But I need other users liked photos. Is this possible? (PHP btw)

Comment: Never worked with the API before, but it doesn't seem like you can get the likes for a user other than yourself - [Instagram API User Endpoints](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the Instagram API. Although they don't say it literally, you can deduce it from [here](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_feed_liked) that you can't:

> See the list of media liked by the authenticated user. Private media is returned as long as the authenticated user has permission to view that media. Liked media lists are only available for the currently authenticated user.

If you are building a big application, you can always store that info from the people who is logging in, or storing the likes while you load pictures, but it can't be updated "live" and I also have my doubts about if it is legal or not.